# Changing Img Attribute with filled array error

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, error-handling

I am fairly new to JavaScript and am having some difficulty understanding why this small bit of code does not work correctly. In the Function 'change(slide)', if I use the alert() function to display any of the array passed to it, then the expected result is displayed. However, when I wish to assign the result to the src attribute of my image I receive an error stating

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

I am looking for the most proper and efficient way to assign my variegating src text into my image.

```
function loadSlider(){
    var stocker = new Array();

    for(var i = 0; i<15; i++){
        stocker.push("C:\\Users\\Rickep\\random_pics\\"+i+".jpg");

    }

    return stocker;
}   

var slider = new Array();
slider = loadSlider();
change(slider);



function change(slide){
document.getElementById('imageToFill').setAttribute('src',slide[1]);

}


</script>   

<div id="filler">
    <img id="imageToFill"></img>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are firing `change(slider);` before the img tag is created.

adding `onload="change(slider);"` to your body tag (and removing the current call) should fix.

if you are using JQuery this could also be `$('document').ready(function(){change(slider);});` instead of the current call to change.

take a look at [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.setInterval) for actually swapping your image.

```
var currentSlide = 0;
$('document').ready(function(){
   setInterval(change, 5000); // 5 seconds
});

function change(){
  currentSlide = (currentSlide+1) % slider.length;
  document.getElementById('imageToFill').setAttribute('src',slider[currentSlide]);
}
```

Comment: I actually implemented this along with some jquery animations to make it appear smooth. Thank you for the solution, now I need to figure out how to auto crop the images to one proper size.